# Insert character after first match using sed or awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a txt file contains a count with text description:

```
12 CASH
10 Tree
7 Computer Desk
```

Ideally I'd like to end up with

```
| CASH | 12 |
| Tree | 10 |
| Computer Desk | 7 |
```

I tried this awk statement below, which kind of works, but then I lose anything after the first word of the description. I feel like I should be using sed, but I'm struggling to come up with a workable solution.

```
awk '{ print "|" $2 "|" $1 "|" }' temp.txt
```

Result:

```
| CASH | 12 |
| Tree | 10 |
| Computer | 7 |
```

Comment: what is the column separator? Otherwise "computer" and "desk" may look like different columns.

Comment: perl is good for this: `perl -lane '$v = shift @F; print "| @F | $v |"' temp.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]+(.*)/| \2 | \1 |/' file
```

---

`-E` (undocumented) or `-r`: enable [extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-regexps)

`[0-9]+`: match one or more digits (range 0 to 9)

`[[:blank:]]`: a [Posix character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275332/how-to-use-double-brackets-in-a-regular-expression/12276342#12276342) and represents a space or a tab

Comment: I'd suggest `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[\t ]`

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes! Thank you for this hint. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I was doing the same, but I was blocked using `\d`, which can be written using `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: That worked, but do you mind explaining it? I get sed is searching for a number with zero or more digits, but then I'm lost after the `\t*`

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` is a [Posix character class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275332/how-to-use-double-brackets-in-a-regular-expression/12276342#12276342) and represents a space or a tab. See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: @Rob, The regular expression finds some digits (saves in first capturing group), some whitespace, and then any other text (the description) is saved in second capturing group. The replacement puts the description before the number, as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easy with sed:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/| \2 | \1 |/'
```

Nonspace before the first space goes to `\1`, the rest of the line goes to `\2`.

```
| CASH | 12 |
| Tree | 10 |
| Computer Desk | 7 |
```

Comment: I tried this and got the following result: `|12 CASH |  |` and so on.

Comment: Tabs in the input, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Posix version

```
sed 's/\([^[blank:]]\{1,}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}([^[blank:]].\{1,}\)/| \2 | \1 |/' YourFile
```