# bash check if a string has a character more than once

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement

The title actually almost explains it all. I would like to check if a string contains a letter (not a specific letter, really any letter) more than once.

for example:

user:

```
test.sh this list
```

script:

```
if [ "$1" has some letter more then once ]
then 
do something
fi
```

Comment: what ouput do you expect ? Yes or No or the letter ? the number of occurences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Posix character class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276342/3776858):

```
if [[ $1 =~ [[:alpha:]].*[[:alpha:]] ]]; then
  echo "more than one letter"
fi
```

Comment: one more question. Would the code also work if you changed the [[:alpha:]]'s with [[a-z]]?

Comment: If you only want small letters use a [range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545751/how-to-back-reference-inner-selections-in-a-regular-expression/1553171#1553171) with only one bracket on each side: [a-z].*[a-z]

Comment: This just checks that a string has at least two letters; I thought the goal was to have something like `aa` be accepted but `ab` rejected.

Comment: @Cyrus Well ... a range will work correctly for ASCII chars between a and z `if, and only if` the LC_COLLATE (or LANG) is set to C. More detail in my answer.

Comment: @chepner I did it (detect `aa`, I mean) !!.

Answer (score 0):

This regex (in bash) will tell you the first lower case letter that is repeated.
And **which** is it:

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="([a-z]).*\1"
if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "more than one letter ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Call as:

```
$ script.sh "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZz"
more than one letter "z"
```

Of course, the range of letters could be changed to lower and upper:

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

But only if the LC_COLLATE is set to "C", if that is set to UTF-8, then also accented characters could be included in the a-z range. As this may show:

```
$ ./sc.sh abcdefghijklémnopéqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZz
more than one letter "é"
```

This will keep letters as what ASCII believe a letter is:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C ./sc.sh abcdefghijklémnopéqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZz
more than one letter "z"
```

The range of characters could be some of the [POSIX character ranges](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

```
[[:word:]] [[:alpha:]] [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]]
```

Please note that what those ranges mean is also changed by the character set in use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go by using just basic commands, you can use something like this ...

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin/:/usr/bin/:$PATH
if [ `echo $* | tr -d ' ' | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | tr -s ' ' |  sort -n | grep -v '^ 1 ' | wc -l`  -ge 1 ]
then
    echo "Input contains duplicate characters"
fi
```

In case it is unclear, it will be easy to try it out each step on the command line like this ... `echo test input | tr -d ' '`see the output, then add the `sed` part to it and so on and so forth.

The first `tr -d ' '` will ensure spaces from your input are not counted as duplicates. For example, if the input is "abcd efgh ijkl", the only character repeating is the space. If you keep `tr -d ' '` in there, the script will not count the input to be having duplicate characters, if you remove it, the script will count the input to be having duplicate characters.

Cheers.

-- Parag